# Keep my IntentService alive when phone is off

Tags: android, location, background-process, intentservice

My IntentService checks the user's location. I need to keep it alive while the phone is turned off. In this Service I have an infinite while loop. The OS will shut it down after 8 minutes.

What other ways can I do this instead of the AlarmManager?

Answer (score 1):

IntentService is supposed to be executed once. When job is done, it terminates. You may try using ordinary Service and do all work on background thread. But, system can stop this service anyway if it is low on resources. To prevent that, you can use .setForeground() method in Service and Service will not be stopped by system. But, there will be icon in notification tray.